# show or hide controls based on databound values

Tags: asp.net

I have a section in an edit form (using `<asp:FormView>`) which I would like to display in a different way depending on the value of a databound field.

It currently looks something like this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ClosedBy") != null %>'>
   Closed by user <%# Eval("ClosedBy") %> on <%# Eval("ClosedDate") %>
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Reopen" OnClick="Reopen" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ClosedBy") == null %>'>
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
```

(I have simplified this example slightly, there is a bit more content in both the Panels.)

Is there a better way of dealing with this?
Is there a way to avoid writing the display condition twice, once for the 'if' Panel and once for the 'else' Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the backend code in the OnLoad handler for your page.
OnLoad fires right after the page has loaded and is databound, so your panels and the data source are both available.

You will need to provide both panels with an ID like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="closedByPanel" runat="server">
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
```

and in your backend code you can now do this :

```
protected void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  closedByPanel.Visible = (someDomainItem.ClosedBy != null);
}
```

Comment: "OnLoad fires right after the page has loaded and is databound" -- no, the timing of OnLoad is not dependent on when the page is databound, and most pages will be databound long after OnLoad has fired. The "OnDatabinding" event might work, but you haven't really answered the question even with that change.